# Error while doing Linear Regression in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm

I am trying to do a simple linear regression in R and I keep getting an error. 
Here is my code:

```
> LinearMod <- lm('2015--teen pregnancy rates' ~ '2012 -- Domestic Violence Calls For Service per 1,000 Residents', data=Copy_of_BNIA_data_7_24_17)
```

I keep getting this error: 
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
  invalid term in model formula

Also here is some more info:

```
> str(Copy_of_BNIA_data_7_24_17)
```

$ 2012 -- Domestic Violence Calls For Service per 1,000 Residents                                              : num  60.5 51.5 56...
 $ 2015--teen pregnancy rates                                                                                   : num  126.3 73.9 69 ...

```
> dput(head(Copy_of_BNIA_data_7_24_17, 10))
```

structure(list( `2012 -- Domestic Violence Calls For Service per 1,000 Residents` = c(60.5, 
51.5, 56.6),
"2015--teen pregnancy rates"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")

Please let me know what the issue is. Thank you!

Comment: Help us help you.  Please give us some information about your data. To start with,  please run both `str(Copy_of_BNIA_data_7_24_17)` and `dput(head(Copy_of_BNIA_data_7_24_17, 10))` and paste the results into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sample data:

```
library(data.table)

Copy_of_BNIA_data_7_24_17 <- data.table("2015--teen pregnancy rates" = c(0,1,4,5),
                 "2012 -- Domestic Violence Calls For Service per 1,000 Residents" = c(10,12,15,16))
```

Linear regression formula:

```
LinearMod <- lm(`2015--teen pregnancy rates` ~ `2012 -- Domestic Violence Calls For Service per 1,000 Residents`, data=Copy_of_BNIA_data_7_24_17)
```

In the `lm` formula you shouldn't put the single quote `'` but the symbol above the tab button: `

Comment: No problem. Friendly advise, for the next time try to build some "sample data", the way i did (doesn't take too long). That way it will be easier for people to help you with your question